# Is there a way to extensions have a variable in a tree view item context menu?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I develop an extension, and I want to show a setting value when the user right clicks a tree view item.

The context menu items are defined statically in the package.json, so it doesn't seem possible by using this method.

However, right clicking a file in the VS Code Explorer tree view shows the keybinding next to the respective command.

Also, GitLens have "Open Changes with Previous Revision" and "Show File History" that also shows the keybind next to the command name (but not aligned to the right). I couldn't find out how they did it.

I want to add a file path next to a command in the context menu. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: look in the package.json of GitLens how they define this menu option. You can use config settings in the `where` clause

Comment: https://github.com/eamodio/vscode-gitlens/blob/master/package.json

There isn't any `where` property in this package.json

Can you link here about this where?

Comment: all contributed commands have a `where` in this json, up to the simple `false`

Comment: Aren't you confusing `when` with `where`?

Comment: OK, find the command that acts the way you want and see how it is implemented